# Using bearer authentication token from IdentityServer in Swagger

Tags: .net, swagger, identityserver4, swagger-ui

This seems like a common problem that people would have, but I'm having trouble finding information about it, maybe I'm bad at searching.

I have a .NET solution, one of the projects is an API project. Every controller in this project has the `Authorize` attribute on it, so when you use Swagger to try and use the endpoints, you get a 401 error every time. It requires an Authorization header attribute with the bearer token to get results from any endpoint.

Another project in the solution is the IdentityServer project, which is handling all the authentication and authorization. There's a web project that redirects to the IdentityServer url to authenticate, which passes the token back to the web project with a callback url, and then the web project uses that token for future requests to the API.

My problem is that Swagger is currently useless for the API, since every endpoint needs the auth token that the API currently can't get, and I'm having trouble finding any information at all for how I can set up this connection between Swagger and the IdentityServer.

Is there a way to do that, or do I need to make separate Authorization endpoints in the API project that will generate the token? Any sort of walkthrough would help.